# manipulate tuple into a list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following variable for class label in my dataset:

```py
y = np.array([3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2])
```

To determine the number of each class,  I do:

```py
np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 5, 9]))
```

How then do I manipulate this into a list of tuples for `(label, n_samples)`? So that I have:

```py
[ (1,1), (2,5), (3,9) ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple list, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
out = list(zip(*np.unique(y, return_counts=True)))
```

Output: `[(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 9)]`

Alternatively, you can create an array with:

```
np.vstack(np.unique(y, return_counts=True)).T
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 9]])
```

Comment: just curious to ask, what is the meaning of the start just before np. call? I mean `*np.unique(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = [1, 2, 3]

# option 1
list_of_tuples = list(
    map(
        lambda x, y: (x, y),
        list_1,
        list_2
    )
)

#option 2
list_of_tuples = [
    (list_1[index], list_2[index]) for index in range(len(list_1))
]

# option 3
list_of_tuples = list(zip(list_1, list_2))

print(list_of_tuples)
# output is [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```